# How can I make this F# more functional?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am currently learning myself a little F# and have written the following code to practice.

The code uses the Mono.Cecil library to inject some IL at the start of every method in each .net assembly found in a given directory. The IL will call a LogMe method in a Loggit.dll assembly.

I want to make this code as functional and idiomatically F# as possible.

My main concern is that the method to inject code into an assembly has some definite side effects. This is unavoidable as thats what the whole point is. I do this in the function InjectMethods. This function is passed to the DoOnModule function.

This DoOnModule function is used twice -

- once when injecting methods - a method with side effects and no real return value,
- and once when retreiving the LogMe method reference from the Loggit.dll assembly - a method with no side effects and a useful return value.

I feel a little uneasy about this double use, which doesnt feel very functional - and yet I find it very useful save code repetition...

How can I make this code more functional?

```
// 
open System.IO
open Mono.Cecil
open Mono.Cecil.Cil

exception LogNotFoundError of string

let IsClass(t:TypeDefinition) =
    t.IsAnsiClass && not t.IsInterface

let UsefulMethods(t:TypeDefinition) =
    t.Methods |> Seq.filter ( fun m -> m.HasBody ) 

// Perform the given funtion on the module found at the given filename.
let DoOnModule fn (file:string) =
    try
        let _module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule file 
        Some ( fn ( _module ) )
    with
        | :? System.BadImageFormatException as ex -> printfn "%A" ex; None
        | :? System.Exception as ex -> printfn "%A" ex; None

// Do the given function on the dll filenames found in the given directory
let MapAssemblies fn directory = 
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory) |> 
    Seq.filter(fun file -> file.EndsWith("dll") || file.EndsWith("exe") ) |>
    Seq.map( fn )

// Return the methods found in the given module
let GetMethods(_module:ModuleDefinition) =
    _module.Types |> Seq.filter ( IsClass ) |> Seq.collect ( UsefulMethods )

// Get the log method found in the Loggit.dll.
// A call to this method will be injected into each method
let LogMethod (_module:ModuleDefinition) = 
    let GetLogMethod(_logmodule:ModuleDefinition) =
        let logClass = _logmodule.Types |> Seq.filter ( fun t -> t.Name.Contains ( "Log" ) ) |> Seq.head
        let logMethod = logClass.Methods |> Seq.filter ( fun m -> m.Name.Contains ( "LogMe" ) ) |> Seq.head
        _module.Import logMethod
    "Loggit.dll" |> DoOnModule GetLogMethod 

// Injects IL into the second method to call the first method, 
// passing this and the method name as parameters
let InjectCallToMethod(logMethod:MethodReference) (_method:MethodDefinition) =
        let processor = _method.Body.GetILProcessor()
        let firstInstruction = _method.Body.Instructions.Item(0)
        let parameter1 = processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, _method.Name)
        let parameter2 = processor.Create(if _method.HasThis then OpCodes.Ldarg_0 else OpCodes.Ldnull)
        let call = processor.Create(OpCodes.Call, logMethod)
        processor.InsertBefore ( firstInstruction, parameter1 );
        processor.InsertBefore ( firstInstruction, parameter2 );
        processor.InsertBefore ( firstInstruction, call )

// Inject a call to the Log method at the start of every method found in the given module.
let InjectMethods(_module:ModuleDefinition) =
    // Inject the call
    let logMethod = LogMethod _module
    match logMethod with
    | Some(log) ->
        let methods = GetMethods _module
        for m in methods do
            m |> InjectCallToMethod log
    | None -> raise(LogNotFoundError("Cant find log method"))

    // Save the module
    Directory.CreateDirectory ( Path.GetDirectoryName ( _module.FullyQualifiedName ) + @"\jiggled\" ) |> ignore
    _module.Write ( Path.Combine ( Path.GetDirectoryName ( _module.FullyQualifiedName ) + @"\jiggled\", Path.GetFileName ( _module.FullyQualifiedName ) ) );

let dir = "D:\\Random\\AssemblyJig\\spog\\bin\\Debug"

// Now inject into the methods
try
    dir |>
    MapAssemblies ( DoOnModule InjectMethods )  |>
    Seq.toList |>
    ignore
with
    | :? System.Exception as ex -> printfn "%A" ex; 

System.Console.ReadLine |> ignore
```

Answer (score 4):

I only have two minor nitpicks with this code:

```
Seq.filter(fun file -> file.EndsWith("dll") || file.EndsWith("exe") ) |>
```

Perhaps this should say `".dll"` and `".exe"`. Or you could use `Path.GetExtension`.

```
Seq.filter ( fun t -> t.Name.Contains ( "Log" ) ) |> Seq.head
```

This will take the first type whose name happens to contain `Log`; even if the name is `ILoggable` or `LogProcessor` or something. Are you sure you know that there will never be any other types with such names than the type you want? The same goes for the method `LogMe`.

Comment: Also using Path.Combine is better than concatenating "\jiggled\" etc.

Comment: Wouldn't Seq.find(...) be a shorter and clearer version of Seq.filter(...) |> Seq.head?